# If a state only always returns to the state that transitioned to it then is it a sustate or a stand alone state?

Tags: state-machine

New to state machines and [dotnet-state-machine](https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless).

I have a path that looks like this from Homed:

```
Homed -> Automatic -> Automatic.Paused (substate of automatic) -> Purge
Homed -> Automatic -> Purge
Homed -> Purge
Homed -> Manual -> Purge
```

The purge is EXACTLY the same in all four cases. The only difference is where they came from. If a transition is made from any state to purge then when purge is finished it needs to go back the the state it came from. A purge can only return back to the state it came from ... ever. It never can go to another state.

How is this normally done? It seems like I have two options:

Have one state "Purge" and keep track of where it came from so when it's time to go back I make the transition back to the state it came from.

-OR-

Do I have four discrete substates for purge where they are each of substate of the state it came from?

I have tried charting this out with Purge as a stand alone state and the chart is quite messy. I have found that in cases like these it helps to understand what the "normal" design pattern is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It you're interested in learning more about state machine programing, and have a 100 hours to spare - checkout TLA+ the state machine checking tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of the options you list here is valid. The separation of persistent variables, transitions, and states is essentially an implementation detail. Much as the use of a state machine for a particular problem is a choice.

Complete state diagrams often end up looking messy. I think it's a reflection of the nature of solving real problems.

My preference is to create new special-case `Purge` states because I think it will result in easier code maintenance. And because hiding real-world complications (in a prior state variable for example) is not ideal unless you can abstract them away thoroughly.

Finally, the academic literature on state machines does not address a state's implementation. If we use a combination of persistent variables and an implementation function that is considered a unique *state*. So, if you carry around an integer variable that is important to your `Purge` state for example, then academically you have as many `Purge` states as valid values for your integer.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. I think the diagram looks much cleaner with different purge states. I see what your logic is - if I have to keep track of what state it came from to the purge then the act of keeping track of where it came from makes the purge a different state. It's not so much what the machine is doing, it's about what the software is doing.

Comment: @Eric Snyder - Better answer than mine.